# quadratic equation solver that not work

Tags: c#, equation-solving

I had create this equation solver (I know that is pretty confusing and maybe I've done stupid mistakes but I started recently), 
                                   but it doesen't works. It doesn't print x1 and x2 on the console.
Can you help me?

```
Console.WriteLine("input the coefficent a");
double a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("input the coefficent b");
double b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("input coefficent c");
double c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double D = Math.Pow(b,2) - 4*(a*c);
Console.WriteLine(D);

double x1;
double x2;

if (Convert.ToBoolean(D = 0))
{
    x1 =  Convert.ToInt32((-b)) / (2 * Convert.ToInt32(a));
    x2 = Convert.ToInt32((-b)) / (2 * Convert.ToInt32(a));
    Console.WriteLine(x1);
    Console.WriteLine(x2);

}
else if (Convert.ToBoolean(D > 0))
{
    x1 = (-b - (Math.Sqrt( Math.Pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
    x2 = (-b + (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
    Console.WriteLine(x1);
    Console.WriteLine(x2);
}
else if (Convert.ToBoolean(D < 0))
    Console.WriteLine("the equation has no real roots");
```

The output is:

> input the coefficent a
>
> 1
>   input the coefficent b
>
> 3
>
> input coefficent c
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> Premere un tasto per continuare . . .

Comment: `if(Convert.ToBoolean(D = 0))` is not what you want. It assigns 0 to D, returns 0 and converts this to false. You want `if (D == 0)` as well as `else if(D > 0)` and `else if(D < 0)`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32((-b))`: Since `b` is a double, you don't need to convert it again. You only need a conversion for `Console.ReadLine()`, since this returns a string which has to be converted to a numeric type; however, I would use `Double.Parse(...)`. Drop all the `Convert.ToInt32`!

Comment: Also `/ 2 * a` divides by `2` and multiplies with `a`. You want `/ (2 * a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(Convert.ToBoolean(D = 0))` is not what you want. It assigns 0 to D, returns 0 and converts this to false. You want `if (D == 0)` as well as `else if(D > 0)` and `else if(D < 0)`

A single = assigns to variables, == compares them.

You also don't need to cast a condition to boolean inside an if-clause, if you need to do this you should think twice if you did something wrong.